# After all performance improvements - AngularJs combined with Angular Material is still slow - any hints?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-material

After all the performance improvements i could find on the internet (e.g.
http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/) my view ist still quite slow - with quite slow i mean that there are peaks with 1500 watchers decreasing to 750. You can really feel the slowness of the app.

This is the view I'm talking about:

```
    <div ng-cloak>
    <md-content class="r-wizard-iosscroll">
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-center-tabs md-selected="tabIndex" class="r-wizardtabs">
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> business_center </md-icon>
                    Jobs
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">Welcome, what kind of job are you looking for?</h2>
                        <div layout layout-align="center center">
                            <md-input-container flex="100">
                                <md-checkbox ng-model="vm.form.full_time" class="md-primary">
                                    Fulltime
                                </md-checkbox>
                                <md-checkbox ng-model="vm.form.part_time" class="md-primary">
                                    Parttime
                                </md-checkbox>
                                <md-checkbox ng-model="vm.form.minijob" class="md-primary">
                                    Minijob
                                </md-checkbox>
                                <md-checkbox ng-model="vm.form.internship" class="md-primary">
                                    Internship
                                </md-checkbox>
                                <md-checkbox ng-model="vm.form.training" class="md-primary">
                                    Apprenticeship (Ausbildung)
                                </md-checkbox>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> fitness_center </md-icon>
                    Skills
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">What skills do you have?</h2>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label></label>
                            <md-chips ng-model="vm.form.skills" md-autocomplete-snap md-transform-chip="transformChip($chip)">
                                <md-autocomplete md-autoselect="true" md-search-text="vm.searchtext" md-items="item in skillSearch(vm.searchtext)" md-item-text="item.label" placeholder="Add skills">
                                    <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchtext">{{item.label}}</span>
                                    <md-not-found>
                                        Enter to create new skill
                                    </md-not-found>
                                </md-autocomplete>
                                <md-chip-template>
                                    {{$chip.label}}
                                </md-chip-template>
                            </md-chips>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <span class="md-subhead">Recommendations</span>
                            <md-chips ng-model="vm.tag_recommendations" placeholder="Add an item" readonly="true" class="r-boxshadow">
                                <md-chip-template ng-click="addTag($chip)">
                                    {{::$chip.label}}
                                </md-chip-template>
                            </md-chips>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> record_voice_over </md-icon>
                    Language
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">What languages do you speak?</h2>
                        <p>Please select your level of German</p>
                        <div layout="column" flex>
                            <md-input-container>
                                <label>German level</label>
                                <md-select ng-model="vm.form.level_german">
                                    <md-option quick-ng-repeat="level in ::refugee_language_skills" value="{{::level.value}}">
                                        {{::level.label}}
                                    </md-option>
                                </md-select>
                            </md-input-container>
                            <p>Please select your level of English</p>
                            <md-input-container>
                                <label>English level</label>
                                <md-select ng-model="vm.form.level_english">
                                    <md-option quick-ng-repeat="level in ::refugee_language_skills" value="{{::level.value}}">
                                        {{::level.label}}
                                    </md-option>
                                </md-select>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        </md-card-content>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> lightbulb_outline </md-icon>
                    Experience
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">Do you have professional work experience?</h2>
                        <md-radio-group class="md-primary" ng-model="vm.pro_exp">
                            <md-radio-button value="1"> yes </md-radio-button>
                            <md-radio-button value="0"> no </md-radio-button>
                        </md-radio-group>
                        <div ng-if="vm.pro_exp === 1">
                            <h2 class="md-title">Where have you worked?</h2>
                            <md-list flex>
                                <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-click="openWorkExperienceDialog(exp)" ng-repeat="exp in vm.form.work_experience" layout-padding>
                                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                        <h3>{{exp.job_title.label}} 
                                        <span class="r-explist-datesize" 
                                        ng-if="exp.from_date.length>0 && (exp.to_date.length>0 || exp.to_present)">({{exp.from_date}} - <span ng-if="!exp.to_present">{{exp.to_date}})</span>
                                         <span ng-if="exp.to_present">present)</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </h3>
                                        <h4>{{exp.company}}, {{exp.location.address}}</h4>
                                        <p>{{exp.description}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons" class="md-secondary" ng-click="deleteWorkExperience(exp.id)"> delete </md-icon>
                                </md-list-item>
                                <md-divider></md-divider>
                            </md-list>
                            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="openWorkExperienceDialog()">+ Add position</md-button>
                        </div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> gavel </md-icon>
                    Legal
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">What is your legal status in Germany?</h2>
                        <legal-card image="mh-aufenthaltserlaubnis.png" description="Aufenthaltserlaubnis (permission to stay)" model="vm.form.refugee_status" value="1" datepicker="vm.form.date_application" statusother="vm.form.refugee_status_other" sidenotes="vm.form.side_notes" applicationdate="vm.form.date_application"></legal-card>
                        <legal-card image="mh-aufenthaltsgestattung.png" description="Aufenthaltsgestattung (temporary resident permit)" model="vm.form.refugee_status" value="2" datepicker="vm.form.date_application" statusother="vm.form.refugee_status_other" sidenotes="vm.form.side_notes" applicationdate="vm.form.date_application"></legal-card>
                        <legal-card image="mh-other.png" description="I'm not sure / other legal status" model="vm.form.refugee_status" value="3" datepicker="vm.form.date_application" statusother="vm.form.refugee_status_other" sidenotes="vm.form.side_notes" applicationdate="vm.form.date_application" class="r-wizard-legalmargin"></legal-card>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> attach_file </md-icon>
                    Attachements
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <h2 class="md-title">Add Attachements</h2>
                        <div layout>
                            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                <input id="fileInputCv" name="file" type="file" class="ng-hide" file-model="vm.cv" aria-label="file input">
                                <md-button ng-click="uploadCV()" class="md-raised md-primary btn btn-medium">+ Add CV </md-button>
                                <div ng-if="vm.cv">
                                    <i>{{vm.cv.name}}</i>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-if="vm.form.cv_id && !vm.cv">
                                    <p>
                                        <i>Click</i> <a href="{{::$root.globals.cdnResource}}cv/{{::vm.form.cv_id}}" target="_blank" class="md-subhead"><i> here </i></a><i>to see your current CV</i>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> contact_phone </md-icon>
                    Contact
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div layout layout-align="center center">
                            <img alt="Your profile image" ng-if="$root.globals.USER.data.image" class="r-profile-image" ng-src="{{::$root.globals.cloudinary.face}}{{$root.globals.USER.data.image}}">
                            <avatar ng-if="!$root.globals.USER.data.image" size="140" name="{{vm.form.first_name}}|{{vm.form.last_name}}"></avatar>
                        </div>
                        <div layout layout-align="center center">
                            <md-input-container>
                                <input id="fileInputImage" name="file" type="file" class="ng-hide fileInput" file-model="vm.image" aria-label="file input">
                                <md-button id="uploadButtonImage" ng-click="uploadImage()" class="md-raised md-primary uploadButton"> Change image </md-button>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="md-title">What is your Name?</h2>
                        <div layout layout-align="center center">
                            <md-input-container flex="50">
                                <label>First Name*</label>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.form.first_name" name="first_name" required minlength="2" maxlength="100" autofocus>
                                <div ng-messages="profileEdit.first_name.$error" ng-if="profileEdit.first_name.$touched && profileEdit.first_name.$invalid">
                                    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength']">
                                        Please enter your First name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container flex="50">
                                <label>Last Name*</label>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.form.last_name" name="last_name" required minlength="2" maxlength="100">
                                <div ng-messages="profileEdit.last_name.$error" ng-if="profileEdit.last_name.$touched && profileEdit.last_name.$invalid">
                                    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength']">
                                        Please enter your Last name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="md-title">How can we reach you?</h2>
                        <div layout layout-align="center center">
                            <md-input-container flex="50">
                                <label>Your German phonenumber</label>
                                <input type="tel" ng-model="vm.form.phone_number" name="phone_number">
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container flex="50">
                                <label>Your WhatsApp number</label>
                                <input type="tel" ng-model="vm.form.whatsapp_number" name="whatsapp_number">
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="md-title">In which city do you live?</h2>
                        <address-input location="vm.form.location" label="e.g Berlin" ng-cloak></address-input>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
<div class="r-wizard-bottombar">
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <div layout layoutNo-align="start center" flex="50">
            <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="continue()">Not now</md-button>
        </div>
        <div layout layout-align="end center" flex="50">
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="save()">Save & Continue</md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controller accordingly:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  function refugeeProfileEditWizard($http, $compile, $rootScope, angularLoad) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: refugeeProfileEditWizardController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: "components/profile_edit/profile_edit_wizard.html",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var input = angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput'));
        var button = angular.element(document.querySelector('#uploadButton'));

        if(input.length && button.length) {
          button.on('click', function (e) {
            input[0].click();
          });
        }
      },
    };

    return directive;

    function refugeeProfileEditWizardController($scope,
      authenticationService,
      notificationService,
      $rootScope,
      $state,
      tagsService,
      refugeeService,
      googleMapsService,
      userService,
      $window,
      $stateParams,
      $mdDialog,
      workExperienceFactory,
      profileEditFactory,
      mixpanelService) {

      //Settings
      $scope.refugee_language_skills = profileEditFactory.refugee_language_skills;

      $scope.vm = {
        searchtext: null,
        tag_recommendations: [],
        form: {
          skills: []
        },
        type: $stateParams.type,
      };

      var tagRecTimeout = null;
      var tagRecInit = true;

      var refugeeId = $rootScope.globals.USER.data.id;

      var _private = this;
      _private.imageUploadInitialized = false;
      _private.cvUUploadInitialized = false;
      _private.tabInitialized = false;

      var tabObject = ["jobs", "skills", "language", "experience", "legal", "attachements", "contact"]

      $scope.tabIndex = 0;

      _private.tabState = function () {
        if($stateParams.tab) {
          var index = tabObject.indexOf($stateParams.tab);
          if(index > -1) {
            $scope.tabIndex = index;
          }
        }
      };
      _private.tabState();

      _private.getProfile = function () {
        refugeeService.getById(refugeeId).then(function (response) {
          $scope.vm.form = response;
          if(response.work_experience.length > 0) {
            $scope.vm.pro_exp = 1;
          } else {
            if($stateParams.type == "welcome") {
              $scope.vm.pro_exp = 1;
            } else {
              $scope.vm.pro_exp = 0;
            }

          }
        });
      };
      _private.getProfile();

      _private.getTagRecommendations = function () {
        var included = "";
        var tags = angular.copy($scope.vm.form.skills);
        for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          included += tags[i].label + ",";
        }
        if(tags) {
          included = included.substring(0, included.length - 1);
        }
        tagsService.getTagRecommendationsRandom(included, included).then(function (response) {
          $scope.vm.tag_recommendations = response;
        });
      };
      _private.getTagRecommendations();

      $scope.openWorkExperienceDialog = function (work) {
        $mdDialog.show({
          controller: "workExperienceCtrl",
          templateUrl: 'components/profile_edit/work_experience.html', //add right component
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          clickOutsideToClose: true,
          onRemoving: completeWorkExperienceDialog,
          locals: {
            work: angular.copy(work),
          }
        });

        function completeWorkExperienceDialog() {
          var workExperience = angular.copy(workExperienceFactory.getValue());
          if(workExperience.job_title.label && workExperience.job_title.label.length > 0) {
            if(!$scope.vm.form.work_experience) {
              $scope.vm.form.work_experience = [];
            }
            if(work) {
              var workIndex = _private.getWorkIndex(work.id);
              if(workIndex > -1) {
                $scope.vm.form.work_experience[workIndex] = workExperience;
              }
            } else {
              $scope.vm.form.work_experience.push(workExperience);
            }

          }
        }
      };

      $scope.deleteWorkExperience = function (workId) {
        var workIndex = _private.getWorkIndex(workId);
        if(workIndex > -1) {
          $scope.vm.form.work_experience.splice(workIndex, 1);
        }
      }

      _private.getWorkIndex = function (workId) {
        var workArray = angular.copy($scope.vm.form.work_experience);
        var workIndex = -1;
        for(var i = 0; i < workArray.length; i++) {
          if(workArray[i].id === workId) {
            workIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        return workIndex;
      }

      $scope.addTag = function (tag) {
        $scope.vm.form.skills.push(tag);
      };

      $scope.skillSearch = function (query) {
        return tagsService.getTagsByQuery(query).then(function (response) {
          return response;
        });
      };

      $scope.transformChip = function (tag) {
        //Thats a new tag
        if(!tag.id) {
          tagsService.createNewTag(tag).then(function (response) {
            $scope.vm.form.skills.push(response);
          });
          return null;
        } else {
          return tag;
        }
      };

      $scope.$watch("tabIndex", function () {
        if(_private.tabInitialized) {
          if($scope.tabIndex <= tabObject.length - 1) {
            $state.transitionTo("refugee-profile-edit", {
              type: $stateParams.type,
              tab: tabObject[$scope.tabIndex],
            }, {
              notify: false
            })
          }
        } else {
          _private.tabInitialized = true;
        }
      });

      $scope.save = function () {
        _private.saveProfile();
      };

      _private.saveProfile = function () {
        $rootScope.globals.loading = true;
        refugeeService.save(angular.copy($scope.vm.form), refugeeId).then(function (response) {
          $rootScope.globals.loading = false;
          _private.saveSuccessful();
        });
      };

      _private.saveSuccessful = function () {
        refugeeService.getById(refugeeId).then(function (response) {
          mixpanelService.setRefugee(response);
          response.step = tabObject[$scope.tabIndex];
          mixpanel.track("profile_edit save_profile click success", angular.copy(response));
          _private.continue();
        });
      };

      $scope.continue = function () {
        mixpanel.track("profile_edit continue click", {
          "step": tabObject[angular.copy($scope.tabIndex)]
        });
        _private.continue();
      };

      _private.continue = function () {
        var tabIndex = angular.copy($scope.tabIndex);
        tabIndex += 1;
        if(tabIndex >= tabObject.length) {
          if($scope.vm.type == "welcome") {
            $state.transitionTo("refugee-profile", {
              id: refugeeId,
              type: "welcome"
            });
          } else {
            $state.transitionTo("refugee-profile", {
              id: refugeeId
            });
            notificationService.toast('Saved successfully!');
          }
        } else {
          $scope.tabIndex += 1;
        }
      };

      //When tags changing - update the recommendations
      $scope.$watchCollection("vm.form.skills", function () {
        if(tagRecInit) {
          tagRecInit = false;
        } else {
          if(tagRecTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(tagRecTimeout);
          }
          tagRecTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            _private.getTagRecommendations();
          }, 100);
        }
      });

      //UPload image
      $scope.uploadImage = function () {
        var inputImage = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#fileInputImage'));
        inputImage[0].click();
      };

      $scope.$watch("vm.image", function () {
        if(_private.imageUploadInitialized) {
          $rootScope.globals.loading = true;
          userService.uploadImage($scope.vm.image).then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.globals.USER.data.image = response.image_url;
            $rootScope.globals.loading = false;
            notificationService.toast('Changed image successfully!', 4000);
          });
        } else {
          _private.imageUploadInitialized = true;
        }
      });

      //Upload CV
      $scope.uploadCV = function () {
        var input = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#fileInputCv'));
        input[0].click();
      };

      $scope.$watch("vm.cv", function () {
        if(_private.cvUUploadInitialized) {
          $rootScope.globals.loading = true;
          refugeeService.uploadCV($scope.vm.cv).then(function () {
            $rootScope.globals.loading = false;
            notificationService.toast('Uploaded CV successfully!', 4000);
          });
        } else {
          _private.cvUUploadInitialized = true;
        }
      });

      function cleanTags(tags) {
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          if(isAnyObject(tags[i])) {
            array.push(angular.copy(tags));
          }
        }
        return array;
      }

      function isAnyObject(value) {
        return value !== null && (typeof value === 'object' || typeof value === 'function');
      }
    }

  }
  angular
    .module('refugeeHire.components.refugee_profile_edit_wizard', [
      "refugeeHire.directive.filemodel",
      "refugeeHire.services.notification",
      "refugeeHire.services.tags",
      "refugeeHire.services.refugee",
      "refugeeHire.services.user",
      "refugeeHire.directive.autoopen",
      "refugeeHire.components.work_experience",
      "refugeeHire.components.work_experience.factory",
      "refugeeHire.components.profile_edit.factory",
      "refugeeHire.directive.legalcard",
      "refugeeHire.components.address_input"
    ])
    .directive('refugeeProfileEditWizard', refugeeProfileEditWizard);
})();
```

Any ideas how to improve the performance here?

Comment: In my experience, avoid the use of $rootScope at all!!! Each value in the $rootScope is watched and evaluated on every $digest cycle, in every controller, no mather if you are in this view or any other. Instead use a Service, they are singletons and if you share the same service across differents controller, they are gonna share the same data. Avoid watchers too.
I guess you should never attach the rootScope to the templates.
Don't do DOM manipulation in the controller, they are expensive as hell!!!
And Chips... they are cool, i really love chips with autocomplete, but they are expensive.

Comment: And another tip, make your controllers slim. Fragment the views, split in differents controllers To myself, i try to write controllers with less than 100 lines.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I think the rootScope thing definitely makes sense!! Will try it - should save around 40 watchers. Also the DOM manipulation in the controller makes sense!! I forgot to remove it :)

Comment: Tell me if works to add this as an answer ;)

Comment: It definitely helped :) But the biggest performance was to remove the tabs - the tabs in angular material just suck out a lot of performance.

The idea is to only use the tabs as kind of a menu and then control the content with ng-if (tabIndex).

You can still ad this is answer since it had impact!!

Comment: wow, almost every tags are angular directives, no wonder it will slow.